# How to unset a fullscreen display on X11

Tags: c, linux, fullscreen, x11, xlib

I got a x11 fullscreen window working, but I can't exit it. I don't understand why there are so many answers about entering fullscreen mode but none about leaving it.

I used this code to set fullscreen:

```
Atom wm_state = XInternAtom (display->display, "_NET_WM_STATE", 1);
            Atom wm_fullscreen = XInternAtom (display->display, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", 1);
            XEvent xev;
            memset(&xev, 0, sizeof(xev));
            xev.type = ClientMessage;
            xev.xclient.window = display->window;
            xev.xclient.message_type = wm_state;
            xev.xclient.format = 32;
            xev.xclient.data.l[0] = 1;
            xev.xclient.data.l[1] = wm_fullscreen;
            xev.xclient.data.l[2] = 0;
            XSendEvent(display->display, DefaultRootWindow(display->display), False, SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask, &xev);
```

I tried changing from `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` to various vaues, like `_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN` and `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE`, but none worked. I confess I don't understand exactly how this code works so that is another obstacle to getting it working. If someone understand about how sending an event with an atom containing some strange message can leyt my window full I would thank, but my focus here is to getting a disable fullscreen working.

Comment: The `data.l[0]` is the on/off bit. Set to `1` to enable fullscreen, set to `0` to disable it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the documentation that explains how that works? I still did'nt found it.

Comment: [X Desktop Group’s _Extended Window Manager Hints_](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/index.html) (Specifically, [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm45164785855248).)